What is the meaning of the notation $2^{2^L}$ and $2^{ 2^L \times 2^L}$ where $2^L$ is P(L)
I'm reading the paper A Pragmatic BDI Architecture1 by Fischer, Müller, and Pischel, and have run across a bit of notation I don't recognize.
They use $2^L$ to mean the power set of L, as best as I can tell. But they then proceed to reference an object notated as $2^{2^L}$. and then another as $2^{2^L \times 2^L}$. I can't recall having seen this before, and don't know what it means. And searching Google, this SE site, Wikipedia, etc. has yet to turn up a clear answer. Does anyone know how this should be interpreted? Is it as simple as "The power set of the power set of L" and "The power set of (the power set of L cross the  power set of L)" respectively?
If so, I guess my set theory just isn't strong enough for this, as I have yet to encounter the idea of "the power set of the power set".
Anyway, in case more context will help, here's the full expression:
At layer i, situations are mapped to goals by a function $\beta_i : S_i \mapsto G_i$ where the function $SG_i : 2^L \times \tau \times 2^{2^L} \times 2^L \mapsto 2^{2^L x 2^L}$ is defined as...

I mean the power set, cartesian product, etc are just operators and operations on the space of sets. You can compose them. That’s all this is. Imagine a high schooler learning multiplication and exponentiation but then being befuddled at compound expressions in them.

I know enough to know that simplistic analogies to high-school mathematics don't always hold up, but not enough to be sure that "the power set of the power set" is what's being said here. Thanks for clarifying, but what did saying " Imagine a high schooler learning multiplication and exponentiation but then being befuddled at compound expressions in them" add to the conversation?

You've got it right. Take the set $L=\{1,2,3,4\}$ for example.

A subset of L. A subset of $L$ a selection of some of the elements in the set $L$. For example, $\{1,3,4\}$ is a subset of $L$. As a special case, the empty set $\{\}$ and the whole set $L=\{1,2,3,4\}$ count as subsets of $L$.

$2^L$: Each member is a subset of L. The power set of $L$ consists of all the subsets of L. Sets like $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\varnothing$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

$2^{2^L}$ Each member is a collection of subsets of L The power set of the power set of $L$ is just:  a collection of some of the subsets of $L$.
For example, there's a collection containing $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\varnothing$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has four things in it.  This collection of four things is just one example of a member of the power set of the power set of $L$.

$2^L \times 2^L$. Each member is an ordered pair of subsets of L This is: any two subsets of $L$, possibly the same two subsets. For example, $\langle \{1,2\}, \{1,2,4\}\rangle$ is a pair of subsets of $L$. So is $\langle \{3,4\},\{3,4\}\rangle$.

$2^{2^L\times 2^L}$. Each member is a collection of ordered pairs. This is the power set of $2^L\times 2^L$. In other words, it consists of all subsets of $2^L\times 2^L$: You may pick any number of pairs of subsets of $L$ you like. That's a subset of $2^L \times 2^L$.
As an example, $\{ \;\langle \{1,2\}, \{1,2,4\}\rangle, \, \langle \{3,4\},\{3,4\}\rangle, \, \{\varnothing, \{2\}\rangle\;\}$ is a member of this set. It has three pairs of things in it.


Aside
As a high-level aside, I suspect the paper is explaining things in terms of formalism in order to be mathematically precise, but that there's probably an intuitive plain language explanation.
Edit: Oh, I see that in the following paragraph, they give the intuitive explanation. At a glance, it looks like:

$L$ is a "language of situation descriptions", roughly "formal sentences that describe the world, either how it is or how you believe it is or how you want it to be".
$SG$ takes in your belief state, the current time $\tau$, and the collection of world-states you're able to monitor at this level, and returns a bunch of situation-goal pairs such that the situation causes you to have a goal.
a "state" is a collection of sentences.
a belief-state is a collection of sentences about how you think the world is.
a single world-state is a collection of sentences about how the world is. you monitor several world states, so in the formalism, that's several different collections of sentences.
a single situation-goal pair is a pair of states. the function can produce several of these, so that's a list of pairs of states.

Hope that helps— sometimes the formalism is a way of describing things precisely, and there's an intuitive explanation underneath.
